# Room database @Database annotation showing Databinding error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room, android-databinding

I am using data binding and room database.
All is working fine bt when i am adding @Database annotation its showing following error :
[image]

after commenting // @Database annotation it working fine bt i am not able to use room database.

[image]

i have added gradle for room db is following

```
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
```

Comment: please add contactDB

Comment: Already added, other annotation of room db like  `@PrimaryKey` `@ColumnInfo` `@Query`  `@Insert`  `@Update`  `@Delete` added successfully on **@Database** annotation creating problem.

Comment: I guess @Basi meant add you creation of `ContactDB.java`. You might have some error other there

Comment: Did u find a solution?

Comment: Yes, I found the solution.
The problem was in ContactsDBDAO class. thats why it was fine after commenting 
@Database(entities = ContactDBModel.class,version = 1,exportSchema = false).
The main problem was miss matching column name in  @ColumnInfo(name = "_name") which were doing the query in ContactsDBDAO

If you have same error please check all entries and column name for avoiding mismatching